# php array and returning a default value?

Tags: php, arrays

Here is my code:

```
<div class="search-menu">
  <div class="btn-group fc">
    <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
      <?php
        $currencies = explode(',', hana_get_opt('_cc'));
        foreach ($currencies as $currency) {
          if ($currency == get_option('woocommerce_currency')){
            echo $currency;
            break;
          }else{
            echo "Select Currency";
            break;
          }
        }
      ?>
      <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu currency_switcher">
      <?php
        foreach ($currencies as $currency) {
          if ($currency == get_option('woocommerce_currency'))
            echo '<li><a href="#" class="reset default" data-currencycode="' . $currency . '">' . $currency . '</a></li>';
          else
            echo '<li><a href="#" data-currencycode="' . $currency . '">' . $currency . '</a></li>';
        }
      ?>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Which works great it returns a list of my currencies and updates the page accordingly, I have just on question if the user has yet to set a value I would like it to say either select currency or just apply the first option from my `hana_get_opt('_cc')` array as the default. 
Here is the html generated code:

```
<div class="btn-group fc">
                        <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">undefined<span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu currency_switcher">
  <li><a href="#" class="reset default active" data-currencycode="SEK">SEK</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-currencycode="EUR">EUR</a></li>                                
                        </ul>
                    </div>
```

I am no php coder and much appreciate any help provided 
Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on the assumption that `get_option('woocommerce_currency')` would return `null` if no currency is selected

```
<div class="search-menu">
<div class="btn-group fc">
<a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
  <?php
    $currencies = explode(',', hana_get_opt('_cc'));
    $currentCurrency = get_option('woocommerce_currency')
    if ($currentCurrency === false) {
        echo "select currency";
    }
    else{
        echo $currentCurrency;
    }
  ?>
  <span class="caret"></span>
</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu currency_switcher">
  <?php
    foreach ($currencies as $currency) {
      if ($currency == $currentCurrency)
        echo '<li><a href="#" class="reset default" data-currencycode="' . $currency . '">' . $currency . '</a></li>';
      else
        echo '<li><a href="#" data-currencycode="' . $currency . '">' . $currency . '</a></li>';
    }
  ?>
</ul>
```

replace the if clause `if ( $currentCurrency != null )` with whatever applies, if `get_option('woocommerce_currency')` returns anything other as `null` if not yet set

Comment: actually like this it still doesn't echo select currency if no currency has been designated in the drop down

Comment: what does `get_option('woocommerce_currency')` return, if nothing has been set before?

Comment: according to wordpress documentation `get_option` returns `false` http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option . I altered my answer. That should work

Comment: it still returns undefined as the first option in the drop down followed by the currencies.

Comment: `undefined` sounds to me like a javascript error. Could you add the HTML code generate between the `ul` with the class `dropdown-menu`. I think there is one element in the `currencies` array, that should not be there.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29187/discussion-between-matthiaslaug-and-vimes1984)

Answer (score 1):

```
   if(get_option('woocommerce_currency')==' ')
    {
        $currencies = explode(',', hana_get_opt('_cc'));
          foreach ($currencies as $currency) 
                {

                 if $currency == get_option('woocommerce_currency'){
                     {
                     echo $currency;
                     break;
                       }
                              else{
                                        echo "Select Currency";
                                        break;
                                    }
                 }
    }

    else
    {   
      echo "Select Currency";
       $currencies = explode(',', hana_get_opt('_cc'));
     $currency=$currencies [0];
    }
```

Comment: Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in
on this line: 
                                
    if(isset(get_option('woocommerce_currency')))

Comment: tell me wch variable u r getting input from

Comment: do u have dropdown element? how is user entering the currency?

Comment: a drop down element on the front end the user chooses which currency they want to display the site in from a drop down. thank you for your patience

Comment: what is the drop down name??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28885/discussion-between-ganeshrj-and-vimes1984)